# NodeJS: sending/uploading a local file to a remote server

Tags: node.js, http

I have used the Winston module to create a daily log file for my offline app. I now need to be able to send or upload that file to a remote server via POST (that part already exists)

I know I need to write the file in chunks so it doesn't hog the memory so I'm using **fs.createReadStream** however I seem to only get a 503 response, even if sending just sample text.

**EDIT**

I worked out that the receiver was expecting the data to be named 'data'. I have removed the createReadSteam as I could only get it to work with 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' and a synchronous **fs.readFileSync**. If I change this to 'multipart/form-data' on the php server would I be able to use createReadStream again, or is that only if I change to physically uploading the json file.

I've only been learning node for the past couple of weeks so any pointers would be gratefully received.

```
var http = require('http'),
    fs = require('fs');

var post_options = {
    host: 'logger.mysite.co.uk',
    path: '/',
    port: 80,
    timeout: 120000,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
}

var sender = http.request(post_options, function(res) {
    if (res.statusCode < 399) {
        var text = ""
        res.on('data', function(chunk) {
            text += chunk
        })
        res.on('end', function(data) {
            console.log(text)
        })
    } else {
        console.log("ERROR", res.statusCode)
    }
})

var POST_DATA = 'data={['
POST_DATA += fs.readFileSync('./path/file.log').toString().replace(/\,+$/,'')
POST_DATA += ']}'
console.log(POST_DATA)
sender.write(POST_DATA)
sender.end()
```

Comment: Have you tried uploading the file using something like `curl` to make sure the remote server actually accepts the data? It might have issues with the `application/json` content type. Also, is the logfile actually in JSON format?

Comment: You may have a point here. Is there any difference between uploading a json file or opening a json file and sending it as POST data chunks (not actually sending the file)

Comment: If you send it with `application/json` as `Content-Type`, the file may not get treated as a 'regular' upload. If you want a regular upload, you should consider using either `request` or at least [`form-data`](https://github.com/felixge/node-form-data) because file uploads are not trivial to implement.

Comment: Is that actually what the server expects? It looks pretty weird.

Comment: 503 is server unavailable - is the server down?  http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E503.html

Comment: @bryanmac I think the server in this case sends back a 503 when it receives data in a form it cannot handle.

Comment: @bryanmac it's an appfog server btw. Turns out this error goes away if I manually work out the length of the post data in bytes and set the correct content length. I'm slowly getting there!

Comment: omg... the lack of semicolons here give me a cancer.

Answer (score 11):

After gazillion of trial-failure this worked for me. Using [FormData](https://github.com/form-data/form-data) with [node-fetch](https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch). Oh, and [request](https://github.com/request/request) deprecated two days ago, btw.

```
const FormData = require('form-data');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

function uploadImage(imageBuffer) {
  const form = new FormData();
  form.append('file', imageBuffer, {
    contentType: 'image/jpeg',
    filename: 'dummy.jpg',
  });
  return fetch(`myserver.cz/upload`, { method: 'POST', body: form })
};
```

In place of `imageBuffer` [there can be numerous things](https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data). I had a [buffer](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html) containing the image, but you can also pass the result of  `fs.createReadStream('/foo/bar.jpg')` to upload a file from drive.

Comment: I'd been bashing my head against this for days, and this answer was exactly what I needed.

Comment: what is imageBuffer ? is it filepath ?

Comment: @NikhilPatil Nope. Node.js has actual thing called Buffer to store bytes of data. I've elaborated more in the answer. But you can just peek into the docs. The links are there for a reason.

Comment: Perfect answer, and wonderfully small library sizes too.

Answer (score 9):

copied from https://github.com/mikeal/request#forms

```
var r = request.post('http://service.com/upload', function optionalCallback (err, httpResponse, body) {
  if (err) {
    return console.error('upload failed:', err);
  }
  console.log('Upload successful!  Server responded with:', body);
})
var form = r.form()
form.append('my_field1', 'my_value23_321')
form.append('my_field2', '123123sdas')
form.append('my_file', fs.createReadStream(path.join(__dirname, 'doodle.png')))
```

Comment: Request just deprecated https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142 see my answer using `node-fetch` and `FormData`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60208227/336753

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using axios for uploading it to a remote server.

```
const { default: axios } = require("axios")
const fs = require('fs');

const path = '/path/to/your/file.{extension}'
const file = fs.readFileSync(path) /** Read file */
const stats = fs.statSync(path) /** Get file size in bytes (for content-length) */
const fileSizeInBytes = stats.size;

/** Add appropriate headers */
const headers = {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer Your Token', /** Optional */
  'Content-Length': fileSizeInBytes, /** Recommended to add it */
  'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
}
let url = "https://www.example.com/remote-server-upload-url"

axios.post(url, file, {
    headers: headers,
    maxContentLength: Infinity, /** To avoid max content length error */
    maxBodyLength: Infinity /** To avoid max body length error */
}).then((response) => {
    return response.data
}).catch((error) => {
    return error
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at the [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request#streaming) module.

It will provide you the ability to stream a file to POST requests.

Comment: I see that.  Request allows you to stream a file directly to another request.  Have a look at the documentation.

Comment: From the docs:

fs.createReadStream('file.json').pipe(request.put('http://mysite.com/obj.json'))

Comment: I agree that `request` is very nice, but the remote server is throwing a fit because of the upload so I don't think replacing `http` with `request` will solve the problem :) The original code, albeit a bit verbose, should work.

Comment: Plus I'm trying to learn node where possible. I've looked at request before and might have to as this is quite complex.

Comment: @sidonaldson using great modules made by others is also part of learning Node ;)

Comment: @robertklep when I first started looking at node I found request to be too confusing, almost like it did too much too soon, now I know if I went back and started again it would make a lot more sense.