# sync-request 'ERROR': Error: source.on is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

By using the following code, I'm trying to upload a local file to an url but I keep having "Error: source.on is not a function"
Probably is related to the second parameter of the fd.append, but honestly I don't know what to put there as there are many different approaches and solutions but none worked so far.

Any clues?

```
let file='screenshot.png'
let url='...some url...'

const fd = new FormData()
fd.append('screenshotFile', fs.createReadStream(file), 'screenshot.png')

try {
  request('POST', url', {form: fd})
}
catch(e){
  logger.log('ERROR',e)
}
```

Result :
'ERROR': Error: source.on is not a function

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Same file in itself?

Comment: trying to post a local file to an url

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NodeJS: sending/uploading a local file to a remote server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19818918/nodejs-sending-uploading-a-local-file-to-a-remote-server)

Comment: `fs.readFileSync(file)`

Comment: readFileSync(file) worked. Silly me. Please post it as answer so I can upvote it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[createReadStream](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#filehandlecreatereadstreamoptions) returns a [ReadStream](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#class-fsreadstream), but form data doesn't accept it.

Use [readFileSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fsreadfilesyncpath-options) instead :)